# RegEx pattern to capture specified text from emails

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help creating a RegEx pattern to capture the **bolded** text below (*it isn't actually bolded in the email*). I'm writing a JS script to scrape emails and RegEx is the bane of my existence. I've tried everything and can't get it to match what I need. All emails should be structured similarly, so you can assume:

- There will be a date above the main body text (bolded portion), then a blank line.
- "Budget:" will follow it, preceded by a blank line.

Thank you!

> From: Blogtrottr <123@gmail.com>
> Sent: Friday, January 6, 2023 7:44 AM
> To: abc@example.com
> Subject: All jobs | upwork.com: I need full seo service for our startup service - Upwork
>
> All jobs | upwork.com
>
> All jobs as of January 06, 2023 12:43 UTC
>
>
>
> <[https://www.upwork.com/jobs/need-full-seo-service-for-our-startup-service_~01d82664a3c759dd13?source=rss](https://www.upwork.com/jobs/need-full-seo-service-for-our-startup-service_%7E01d82664a3c759dd13?source=rss)>
> I need full seo service for our startup service - Upwork
>
> Jan 6th 2023, 12:23
>
> **Hello dear how are you we need professional full SEO service for our
> startup service. Our budget is 5$ for this work. if you can do this
> work for me then please bid here. all info given after interview. we
> need 100% professional service dear Thanks.**
>
> Budget: $5.50
> Posted On: January 06, 2023 12:23 UTC
> Category: SEO
> Skills:Search Engine Optimization, SEO Keyword Research, SEO
> Backlinking, Off-Page SEO, SEO Performance, SEO Audit, Organic Traffic Growth
> Country: United States
> click to apply <[https://www.upwork.com/jobs/need-full-seo-service-for-our-startup-service_~01d82664a3c759dd13?source=rss](https://www.upwork.com/jobs/need-full-seo-service-for-our-startup-service_%7E01d82664a3c759dd13?source=rss)>
>
>
>
>
> You are receiving this email because you subscribed to this feed at
> blogtrottr.com <https://blogtrottr.com/> .
>
> If you no longer wish to receive these emails, you can unsubscribe
> from this feed <https://blogtrottr.com/unsubscribe/4mc/Qtw3mD> , or
> manage all your subscriptions <https://blogtrottr.com/subscriptions/> .

Comment: stack overflow is not a site for getting people to write code for you. It's expected that you've attempted to solve the issue yourself, that you post code that reproduced the error and that you explain your previous attempted process.

Comment: I have literally tried everything I can think of. I admittedly suck at RegEx. I've tried to have it capture everything after the date, didn't work. Everything before "Budget:", didn't work. I'm fine with writing it on my own, I need tips on where to start.

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use regex?

Comment: No, it just seemed like the cleanest way to go about it, as there's weird random characters hidden in there and there's no way to tell how it will be formatted from email to email. For instance, the bolded portion here is user input - so there are random newline characters in it, so when I split on \n it gets split into multiple strings. I guess I could just search for the Date (but there are multiple in the email), then "Budget" but there has to be an easier way haha.

Comment: Does anyone know of any tools where you can put the text in and like highlight the portion you need to match and it creates the pattern for you? I've been using https://regexr.com/ which was helpful for the other parts, but it requires you to create the pattern yourself - meaning you have to know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one:

```
/(?<=[A-Z]\w+ \d+(st|nd|rd|th) \d{4}, \d{2}:\d{2}\n\n).*?(?=\n\nBudget: )/gm
```

We use lookarounds to accomplish this: the lookbehind to match the date format and double new line, and the lookahead to match the double new line followed by `"Budget: "`.

[Try it.](https://regex101.com/r/tfoL0q/1)

Comment: https://regexr.com/78mjp
Weird. It appears to work on yours but not on mine or in the actual script. I think something is getting lost when it's being copied. Thanks for trying though! I'll see if I can work backwards from this and get it to work.

Comment: Success! This worked: /(?<=\d{4}, \d{2}:\d{2})([^]*)(?=Budget)/
Thank you sir!